# MXNet Gluon Regression Custom Dataset

Tags: machine-learning, mxnet

ist there a code example on how to do linear regression on a custom image dataset? I have only found examples using the CIFAR dataset...

Comment: Welcome to SO; please do take some time to read [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and notice that questions asking us to *recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource* are off-topic here.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a guide as to how you can make minor modifications to the [MNIST example](https://mxnet.incubator.apache.org/versions/master/tutorials/gluon/mnist.html) to suit your needs. There may be some fiddling.

1. Store your data locally as images in a directory under different categories:

```
train/cats/abc.jpg
train/cats/def.jpg ...
train/dogs/ghi.jpg ...
train/mouse/jkl.jpg ...

analogously for validation
val/cats/...
val/dogs/...
```

The filenames don't matter, just the directories as these will be use to identify the category.

2. Update the MNIST example to use the [ImageFolderDataset](https://mxnet.incubator.apache.org/api/python/gluon/data.html?highlight=imagefolderdataset#mxnet.gluon.data.vision.datasets.ImageFolderDataset) for your test and train data

```
train_data = mx.gluon.data.vision.datasets.ImageFolderDataset(training_path)
val_data = mx.gluon.data.vision.datasets.ImageFolderDataset(val_path)
```

Note, you may need to apply a transform to your images.

3. Replace the network with a single dense layer with no activation and an L2 loss for a linear regression.

```
net = Dense(number_of_outputs)  # activation=None, use_bias=True by default
```

(In the code it's `lenet` instead of `net`.)

More docs: https://mxnet.incubator.apache.org/versions/master/tutorials/gluon/datasets.html

Hope that helps!